# Invoking a bash command with an argument '#' in it

Tags: bash, shell

Consider the following code:

```
sqls='/mnt/c/alias/Binn/SQLCMD.EXE -b -S HostName -U Username -P MyPW# -d dbName'
```

which is the prefix of the command to connect to the SQL Server DB `dbName` with username `Username` on the `HostName`

```
`$sqls -Q "select 1;"`
```

executes `select 1` statement on it and it works as expected.

```
$($sqls -Q "select 1;")
```

fails. Why? Is it because of the '#' in the password? How should I change the sqls line above so it works with `$(...)` expression?

Comment: Learn about bash shell quoting ( https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html ) - you will need to quote your password: `-P 'MyPW#'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing a command in a string is [prone to failure](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). We could work out why it's not working, but the better thing to do would be to use a function:

```
sql() {
  /mnt/c/alias/Binn/SQLCMD.EXE -b -S HostName -U Username -P 'MyPW#' -d dbName -Q "$1"
}
```

This allows the password to be quoted, removing the possibility that it can break the command.

Use it like `sql 'select 1'`. Save the result using a standard command substitution:

```
foo=$(sql 'select 1')
```

Also bear in mind that you can use a config file (possibly `$HOME/.my.cnf`, but it looks like you're on Windows so not sure) to store default user, pass and database, enabling you to run queries without passing all those options every time.

Comment: nice hint to wrap it into a function! And yes, indeed I have a windows server running ubuntu as subsystem. Which makes life a lot easier bringing the unpredictability and complexity as well